# Can't switch between keyboard layouts using Alt+Shift+Number while focus is in text fields and some applications

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I'm running Windows 10, build 1803, and have set up my language like this:

[image: Screenshot]

with three input languages - US English, Bulgarian and Japanese. Each has an assigned shortcut - <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for ENG, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for BGR, and <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for JPN.

Pressing the shortcut for BGR does **not** work in

- Firefox's address bar
- Microsoft Edge's address bar
- Chrome's address bar
- Notepad
- Web page text entry fields (like this one, in Firefox)

but it *does* work in

- Discord
- Skype

After a short while, the shortcuts for ENG and BGR get unset and Windows beeps at me when I press them.

This is a fresh Windows install.

What could be causing this?

Edit: After a bit more testing, if I don't bind a shortcut to the JPN layout, switching also works in Vim 8.1, but it still doesn't work in Notepad or the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on trying to fix this and have switched to using the following AutoHotkey script that lets me switch layouts with win+space. This solves my original problem which was that alt+shift and ctrl+shift are used in certain software so they're not convenient for use by themselves.

```
#Space::
PostMessage 0x50, 0, 0,, A
return
```